# Re-fitting bathroom tiles - what goes behind it?

Tags: bathroom, tile, mortar

I have an issue in my bathroom. We have a window, the inside sill of which is tiled. Some of the grout around our tiles here was perished, but when beginning a re-grout, I noticed the tile was loose.

Underneath the tile was a wooden board that had rotted due to prolonged water ingress.

[image]

I took the wooden board and some perished mortar out, and now I have a large gap where this used to be.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I think the correct thing to fill this gap with is some sand and cement, and then lay a waterproof board on top. Something like [this](https://www.diy.com/departments/aquadry-waterproof-board-l-1200mm-w-600mm-t-12mm/259514_BQ.prd). What do folks think?

Comment: Why use the board at all ?  Just tile on top of of cement/sand

Comment: Assuming the OP can generate a flat surface with the cement/sand.